# Currency regular expression for GBP/USD/EUR

Tags: python, regex, python-3.5, currency

Need some help with creating a regular expression that satisfies the following rules. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**(1a.)** Optionally start with:
    £, $, €

**1b.** Currency value must start with one to three digits

**2a.** Before a comma: There must be one to three digits

**2b.** After a comma: There must be three digits

**2c**. After a decimal point: There can only be digits

**3a.** Currency value must end with one or many digits

**[3b.]** Value may be followed by:
    tn/Tn/Trillion/trillion, bn/Bn/Billion/billion, m/Million/million.

**(3c.)** Optionally end with:
    p/P/Pence/pence, c/C/Cents/cents, €/Euro(s)/euro(s), Dollars/dollars, Pounds/pounds.

**Rule 1a and 3c are mutually exclusive**, however one of them must be used:

```
$1 dollar ✘
1 ✘
$1 ✓
1 dollar ✓
```

**Rule 3b may be used with Rule 1a or 3c**, but does not need to be used:

```
$1 trillion ✓
1 trillion dollars ✓
$1 ✓
```

**Rule 2a/2b may be used zero or many times:**

```
$1 ✓
$1,000,000,000,000 ✓
```

**Rule 2c may only be used once or zero times:**

```
$1 ✓
$1.000 ✓
```

**Expected Result:**

```
$1 dollar ✘
1 ✘
$1,00000.000,000 ✘
1,000.00 ✘

$1 ✓
1 dollar ✓
$1 trillion ✓
1 trillion dollars ✓
$1,000,000,000,000 ✓
$1.000 ✓
$1,000,000,000,000.000000 ✓
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
[£€$]?[0-9]+[,.]?[0-9][pcm][ euros| euro]*
```

Comment: `[ euros| euro]*` -> `(?: euros| euro)?` -> `(?: euros?)?`. BTW, why are you using euros in the pattern if you have dollars in the input?

Comment: I used this as an example as  i want to catch euros, dollars and pounds. for example 5bn euros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex doesn't rely on the values being on separate lines but will also grab them from within a sentence.

It also assumes that the units "cents", "dollars" and "pounds" can be singular.

Plus it allows unlimited whitespace between the words and the number, and also *no* whitespace between the number and the following value word or unit.

**Explanation:**

The following is the basic structure of the regex with sub-expressions represented by values surrounded by two `@`s:

```
(@Prefix@)?(?=(@Value@)(\s*@Postfix@)?)(?(1)\2(?!\3)|(?<!@Prefix@)\2\3)
|________|    |_______||____________|  |______________________________|
    |             |           |                       |
 Group 1       Group 2    Group 3          Prefix-Postfix Selector
```

Group 1 optionally matches the prefix.

Group 2 and Group 3 are captured inside a look-ahead so that when `Prefix-Postfix Selector` is executed, only Group 1 is part of the overall match.

`Prefix-Postfix Selector` is a conditional statement that does the following:

- If Group 1 (`Prefix`) is matched, then add Group 2 (`Value`) to the overall match iff there is no Group 3 (`Postfix`) following it.
- If no `Prefix` is matched, then set the overall match to `Value` followed by `Postfix` iff there is no `Prefix` preceding `Value`.

The sub-expressions are fairly self-explanatory. The `\b`s make sure that entire words are matched. Similarly, the negative look-ahead `(?![\d.,])` after the number makes sure that that no digits, commas and decimal points are left over.

@Prefix@:

```
[£€$]
```

@Value@:

```
\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?(?![\d.,])(?:\s*(?:[tTbB]n|m|(?:[tT]r|[bBmM])illion)\b)?
|_____||_________||________||        ||                                            |
|__________________________||________||____________________________________________|
             |                   |                          |
   Number, e.g. 12,345.6         |    [[Whitespace] + Value Word, e.g. Tn or Billion]
                                 |
           Makes sure "1000" is not matched, for example
```

@Postfix@:

```
\s*(?:[pP](?:ence)?|[cC](?:ents?)?|€|[eE]uros?|[dD]ollars?|[pP]ounds?)\b
```

---

**Solution:**

Replacing the placeholders with the sub-expressions leads to this full regex:

```
([£€$])?(?=(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?(?![\d.,])(?:\s*(?:[tTbB]n|m|(?:[tT]r|[bBmM])illion)\b)?)(\s*(?:[pP](?:ence)?|[cC](?:ents?)?|€|[eE]uros?|[dD]ollars?|[pP]ounds?)\b)?)(?(1)\2(?!\3)|(?<![£€$])\2\3)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/LgtIBy/1)

---

**Caveats:**

- A value like "$1" appearing in a sentence followed by a comma or full stop will not be matched. (For example, only `$2` is matched in the sentence `This sentence is worth $1, $2 or $3.`.)
- A value consisting of a number with commas and/or a decimal point ***and*** a value word is allowed, e.g. "1,000,000 million".

Answer (score 0):

To manage with mutual exclusion you can use grouping for currency sign and test group for plain currency name:

```
^([$£€])?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?\s?(?:(?:[BMbm]|[Tt]r)(?:illion)?)?(?(1)|\s(?:(?:[Dd]ollar|[Pp]ound|[Ee]uro|[Cc]ent)s?|€|[Pp]ence))$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/p1ylk6/2)

Comment: Wasn't quiet what i was after but its very close. Thanks alot.

Comment: Can you explain then?